# Android Light Schedule Interface

Tags: android, touch, android-canvas, schedule

I am just a poor begginner in coding in Android.

I am having an issue making an interface for an application that automatically turns on a light. 
I came up with an idea of an interface, but I don't know how to implement it or how should I start. 
I want it to look similar to this sketch. The colors should change when the user touches a zone. The circles are divided in 48 sections each (each section represents a 15 minutes interval).

You can see the sketch here:
[Sketch](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qyvh1mskcia9s2v/Idee%20selectie%20ore.jpg)

I searched on the internet, but couldn't find something similar.

Help appreciated. Thanks!